# Assert - способ бросить исключения при проверки параметров

Tags: java

Перед тем как я начинаю производить действие над параметрами, я должен проверить, что их прислали такие с которыми я могу работать. С null и с пустым листом я работать не могу, соответственно как мне в этом методе бросить исключительные ситуации с помощью assert на проверку null и пустого list ?

```
public void eat(ArrayList<Food> foodList) {
        if (!foodList.isEmpty()) {
            Food f = foodList.get (foodList.size()-1);
            foodList.remove(foodList.size()-1);
            Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle ("Вкуснота-то какая!");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Кажется, вкус этого блюда: " + f.tasteToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
                    "Овощ: "+ f.getVeget().vegetableToString().toLowerCase() +", цвет блюда: " + f.getVeget().colorToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
                    "В следующий раз добавлю больше перца и лавровый листик");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try catch? или что другое?

Comment: да, try catch тоже сойдёт

Comment: так в чем проблема?!

Comment: в том, как это реализовать

Comment: вы не знаете как использовать конструкцию?

Comment: @Daniil , вы не знаете как лучше обрабатывать исключительные ситуации ? Могу написать ответ, если вопрос в этом

Comment: да, было бы здорово

Comment: Для проверки на null используйте Objects.requireNonNull(). О его преимуществах написано много. Первое это раннее  оповещение о недопустимым параметрах. Если ловить исключения, то это может быть поздно.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець стоило бы отметить что Objects это `java1.7+`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я не думаю, что начинающие стартуют с 1.5. В основном ставят последнюю версию.  А вообще, по-моему Objects это 8

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець я до сих пор вынужден на шестерке писать...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ in the Q Это хорошо, когда есть работа. Наверное я об этом классе узнал вместе с новыми возможностями 1.8, поэтому отложилось в голове 8.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець о работы выше крыши, за всем не успеваю, java уже почти отошла на второй план...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо воспользоваться [исключениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Для выброса исключения в `java` есть директива [`throws`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)

Так же `java` есть специальный тип исключения [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), показывающий что код вызван с некорректными аргументами.

```
public void eat(List<Food> foodList) {
    if (null == foodList || foodList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("foodList cannot be null or empty");
    }

    Food f = foodList.get (foodList.size()-1);
    foodList.remove(foodList.size()-1);
    Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle ("Вкуснота-то какая!");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Кажется, вкус этого блюда: " + f.tasteToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
            "Овощ: "+ f.getVeget().vegetableToString().toLowerCase() +
             ", цвет блюда: " + f.getVeget().colorToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
            "В следующий раз добавлю больше перца и лавровый листик");
    alert.showAndWait();

}
```

Теперь если вызвать метод `.eat()` с аргументом `null` или пустым листом - будет выброшено исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foodList cannot be null or empty
```

Чтобы его поймать и обработать по месту вызова (если необходимо) нужна такая конструкция:

```
  try {
      eat(list);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // логика обработки исключения
  }
```

---

`IllegalArgumentException` является непроверяемым исключением(unchecked exception)  т.к. он унаследован от `RuntimeException` , по этому в вызывающем коде `try-catch` не обязателен

Вот дерево наследования интерфейса `Throwable`, из которого видно что непроверяемыми являются наследники классов `RuntimeException` и `Error`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: извините если слегка сумбурно..